# Find $a\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(23-a)(3-a)$ is square number.

Tags: number-theory

> Find all $a\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(23-a)(3-a)$ is a perfect square.

**My attempt:**

I tried get $23-a=x^2$ and $a-3=y^2$ so that $(23-a)(a-3)$ is a perfect square.

Therefore, $x^2-y^2=23-a-a+3=26-2a$.

Comment: The two factors can have common factors of $2$ or $5$, so do not both have to be square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand the left hand side and complete the square,
$$(23-a)(3-a)=69-26a+a^2=(a-13)^2-100$$
Now, equate it to a perfect square and then factorize,
$$(a-13)^2-100=k^2 \implies  (a-13-k)(a-13+k)=100=2\cdot2\cdot5\cdot5$$
The rest is just case work and should be fairly simple.